# send a mail to particular user while clicking on the button from view page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

i have one view page called vendor view candidates page..in that page i display all the candidates details from database and i have user_id in that  view page..and i gave  button called release information..so when user click on the button the page will redirect to edit_candidates page with that particular candidate_id..and they will allow to insert email and phone number..

After they insert email and mobile number and then submit..i want to send mail to particular user_id..

This is my button:(edit candidates page)

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Candidate/edit_candidates/<?php echo $idata->candidate_id;?>" class="btn btn-info view_col">Release Contact Info</a></td>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit_candidates($id)
{
$data['editdata']=$this->CandidateModel->candidate($id);
if($this->input->post())
{
$this->CandidateModel->update_candidate($this->input->post(),$id);
redirect(base_url('index.php/Candidate/vendor_view_candidates'));
}
$this->load->view('Candidates/edit_candidate',$data);
}
```

Can anyone help me...i tried a lot..but i didn't get any idea on how to do this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: To whom you like to send the email?

Comment: i want to send mail to that particular user...i have that user_id in my candidates table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to fix your issue

```
public function edit_candidates($id)
{ 
    $data['editdata']=$this->CandidateModel->candidate($id); 
    if($this->input->post('update_form'))
    { 
        $userEmail = $this->CandidateModel->get_userinfo($data['editdata']->user_id); 
        //Pass this $userEmail into mail function it will send email

        $this->CandidateModel->update_candidate($this->input->post(),$id); 
        redirect('index.php/Candidate/vendor_view_candidates','refresh'); 
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('Candidates/edit_candidate',$data); 
    }
}
```

Let me know if it not fix your issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898516/how-to-populate-database-values-in-dropdwon-in-laravel/42899041?noredirect=1#comment72903222_42899041