# How to populate database values in dropdwon in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

i want to show the database values in  drop down..i tried a lot but it's not working for me..
i am getting errors i don't know where i mistaken..i am new to laravel..please help me where i mistaken..

view:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">User type</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
        <?php
        {!!Form::select('user_type_id[]', $usertypes_list, $thing->user_type->pluck('id'), ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        ;?>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function get() {
    $usertypes_list = User_type::lists('id', 'type');
    return view('edit')->compact('user_type');
}
```

Can anyone help me...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try this `  {!! Form::select('user_type_id[]', $usertypes_list, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}` and remove the `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: i am getting this error when i try like this Class 'Form' not found

Comment: did you added `laravelcollective` to your project ?

Comment: laravelcollective for what..may i know the purpose

Comment: `Form::select` is not a builtin feature in laravel 5+ it's a package called `laravelcollective` it's very common and useful

Comment: ohh sorry i am new to laravel..so i don't have anyidea on how to use this..

Answer (score 0):

run `composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4"` to add `laravelcollective` to your project as `Form::select` is no longer available in laravel 5+

and have a quick look on [this laravelcollective Doc.s](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html)

**Edit:**
in your controller you've to pass `$usertypes_list` so the function should be

```
public function get() {
    $usertypes_list = User_type::pluck('id', 'type');
    return view('edit')->compact('usertypes_list');
}
```

then your view should looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">User type</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
        {!!Form::select('user_type_id[]', $usertypes_list, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

Comment: when i try to install this i got like this ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Comment: try running `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: now i got this error Undefined variable: usertypes_list

Comment: i want to get values from user-type table

Comment: I've edited the answer. you were passing a non-existing variable to the view `user_type` and calling `$thing->user_type->pluck('id')` which is understandable for me! what's `$thing`?

Comment: no i got same error Undefined variable: usertypes_list

Comment: use `return view('edit')->compact('usertypes_list');` not `return view('edit')->compact('user_type');`

Comment: I forgot that you're using `lists` which is deprecated from laravel 5.3 or 5.2 
 so use instead `$usertypes_list = User_type::pluck('id', 'type');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138520/discussion-between-m-elwan-and-bharathi).

Comment: how to write model for user_type?

Comment: can you please tell me the mistake